# Multiple view select helpers on one page have conflicting value

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need multiple selects:

```
{{view "select" content=contentData optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name" value=model.primary.id}}
{{view "select" content=contentData optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name" value=model.secondary.id}}
```

The problem is that the selected `value` in second one is the same as in the first one. If I comment any one out the second one will work as expected.

Initially I though that only one instance is created. But documentation says otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. ContentData shouldn't be promise.